# Which sentence structure is correct/better and why? Please explain

Tags: syntax

I have applied for admission to post-graduation course at a few universities.

I have applied at a few universities for admission in post-graduation course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of word order, they are both correct and there isn't a particular reason you should use one and not the other. You should consider amending the bits in bold below and also add punctuation:

> I have applied for admission to **a** post-**graduate** course, at a few universities.
>
> I have applied, at a few universities, for admission **to a** post-**graduate** course.

Comment: Thanks very much. Appreciate it

Comment: Is it correct to say "I have applied for admission to the English post-graduate course at a few universities." Or "I have applied for admission to MA English at a few universities."

Comment: Both work :) Please note the comer placement in my examples. They are not strictly necessary, however, they do make the sentence easier to read.

Comment: Thanks very much. I should have used that above. My bad. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! If my answer is sufficient, please can you accept it so that others know you're not still looking for further clarification?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. How do I accept it?

Comment: [Here is a link on accepting answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)